# Tennis league - minimum number of games

Tags: combinatorics

In a tennis league, consisting of 32 players, each player played with each other at least twice and at maximum Q times.
Knowing that each of them participated in a different number of games, can you determine the minimum Q for which the above condition can be met?

What I have done so far:
All possible pairs of 32 players are 32!/2!30!=496.
Given that each pair is taken from 2 to Q times, the total number T of games is from 2*496 to Q*496 (but I am not sure this is correct).
Furthermore, each player played a different number of games, thus we are asking for a series of different numbers that sum up to 2T (because in each game we have two players that participate).
The minimum number of the above series must be 32*2 (because each player played with each other at least twice)?

Comment: This is exactly the variation I posted in my last comment in the previous question. It is not a contest question; it's just one of the (many) riddles & puzzles & maths problems we exchange between friends.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'd noticed neither that it was the same person posting both questions, nor that there was a variation in the question. I've reopened it and removed my comments. (Nevertheless, it would have been a good idea to link to [the original question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759224) and to stick with its terminology and phrasing.)

Comment: OK if we name the players A1 to A32, then the first player participated in 2*31=62 (and not 2*32 that I wrote before) games. All others must have participated in a different number of games. Is it correct to say that we add up all numbers from 62, 63,..., up to 93 (a total of 32 different numbers, one for each player) and then divide by 496*2? But then we get 2.5 which is not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can subtract out the two games that each pair of players played – they just form a baseline, and the games of interest are the additional ones. So we can rephrase the question as: If $n$ players each played a different number of games and the maximal number of games played by any pair is $p$, what is the minimal value of $p$. Then $Q=p+2$.

Let $m$ be the greatest number of games played by a single player. We have $m\ge n-1$. Clearly $p\gt0$. If $p=1$, then $m\le n-1$, so $m=n-1$. But then one player played all other players, so no player played no games, which only leaves $n-1$ different numbers of games to be played, a contradiction. Thus $p=1$ is impossible. For $p=2$, we can exhibit a schedule: Number the players from $1$ to $n$, and let each pair $k,l$ play one game if $k+l\le n+1$ and one more game if $k+l\le n$.

Thus the minimal value of $p$ is $2$, and the minimal value of $Q$ is $2+2=4$.

Comment: Yes but we are told that each pair (k,l) played at least 2 games.

Comment: @Samuel: Yes, I dealt with that in the first paragraph. I subtracted those two games because they just form a distracting baseline. Then I added them back in at the very end.

Comment: "But then one player played all other players, so no player played no games, which only leaves n−1n−1 different numbers of games to be played, a contradiction" - Can you please explain this a little further?

Comment: @Samuel: I had concluded $m=n-1$, and $m$ is the greatest number of games played by a single player. Thus some player played $n-1$ games. I had assumed $p=1$ (in order to derive a contradiction). A player who played $n-1$ games without playing more than $p=1$ games against any player must have played all other $n-1$ players. Then there is no player who played $0$ games. But that leaves only the $n-1$ numbers from $1$ to $n-1$ as possible counts of games the players played. Since there are $n$ players who all had different counts of games, this is a contradiction. I hope that makes it clearer?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but can you also explain the following? "Number the players from 1 to n, and let each pair k,l play one game if k+l≤n+1 and one more game if k+l≤n." First of all, what is k and l? Then, why do we have these two different cases (maybe if you explain what k and l stand for, I will understand the conditions). Thank you!!

Comment: Now that I read it again, I understand it's just a pattern and k, l are two random players.